# What is the probability of getting at-least one even digit for 5 trials.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let we have   through a  fair dice.  What is the probability of getting  at-least one  even digit  for  5 trials.

In this case  I have evaluated  the number of trials as follows:

The  probability  of getting  four odd digit =  $  5 ^C 4   \times ( \frac{1}{2} )^4 \times  \frac{1}{2} = 5 \times  (\frac{1}{2} ) ^5$

Then the probability of getting at least one even digit = $ 1- 5 \times \Big( \frac{1}{2}\Big)^5  $

Is it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting exactly four odds is only one of several ways to get at last one even digit.

What you *should* be considering is how probable it is to get *no* even digits, which is the same as getting exactly *five* odds.

So your answer should be $1-(\frac12)^5$.